# Laravel : Display stdClass object value on select box

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display the value of `username` from DB. I can display if it only 1 value. But the data is not only 1, and I need to display it on select box/ dropdown.

```
$staff = DB::select(DB::raw("select username from customer_type where customer_type ='Staff'"));
```

This is the `print_r` of `$staff`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => test
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => jayusman
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => MuhammadFik
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => test2
        )
)
```

I want to display the username (test, jayusman, MuhammadFik, test2) on the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to loop through the entities

```
<select name="somethin">
@foreach($staff as $key => $name)
 <option value="{{$name->username}}">{{$name->username}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
DB::table('customer_type')
    ->select('customer_id', 'username')
    ->where('customer_type', 'Staff')
    ->pluck('customer_id', 'username')
```

It'll generate an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [2] => 'User #2',
    [5] => 'User #5',
    [7] => 'User #7',
)
```

This way you're able to identify the user by its ID when the form get's submitted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.